# How do I remove selected item on a list?

Tags: c#, list, listview

I am trying to remove a specific item on my list (people) when button (remove) is clicked. Instead, only the display on the listview (listName) is removed. When I create another name, the previous names that I had removed are displayed on the lisview again.

```
public void remove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listName.SelectedItems)
        {
            listName.Items.Remove(eachItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You cannot modify a collection while iterating over it. Sure it runs ok?

Comment: how do you assign the datasource to listview?

Comment: I let the user to enter a name on a textbox and put it on the list (people) then display it on the listview (listName)

Comment: Then you should also remove it from the actual list (people) since that's what your list is using to show items

Comment: Sorry but how do I remove it form the list (people)? I tried this:
Names.People.Remove(eachItem);

Comment: @Cievlh Please upvote the anwser if it worked for you so that others would prefer it

Answer (score 0):

You should make a list of items to remove while enumerating, then use that list to actually remove them, to avoid modifying the collection while enumerating (since modifying `Items` is really also modifying `SelectedItems` which you are currently enumerating):

```
public void remove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemsToDelete = new List<ListViewItem>();
    foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listName.SelectedItems)
    {
        itemsToDelete.Add(eachItem);
    }
    foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in itemsToDelete)
    {
        listName.Items.Remove(eachItem);
    }
}
```